# connecting a host to the internet through an OpenFlow software switch

Tags: networking, network-programming, openflow

I have two Ubuntu virtual machines X and Y.
x has Open vSwitch and floodlight running on it and the Y vm acts as a host.
I have a Host-Only adapter and a NAT adapter attached to X vm. and the Y vm has only a Host-Only adapter.

the host only adapters of X and Y vm's are in the same subnet.

now I want to connect the Y vm to the internet through the OVS running on X vm.
is it possible?
if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get internet connectivity to the host machines only through the Open vSwitch,

USING DHCP

```
1: add the interface connected to internet(say eth0) on the OVS machine to the OVS bridge.
2: change the ip address of eth0 interface to 0 and get a dhcp ip to the bridge interface using dhclient
3: add the interfaces that are connected to the hosts to the OVS bridge
4: get dhcp ip's to the hosts by using dhclient on the host machines
```

USING custom IP addresses

```
1: add the interfaces connected to the hosts and the interface connected to the internet to the OVS bridge
2: make the internet interface ip as 0 
3: set the bridge ip address to the ip address that was previously assigned to the internet interface
4: make sure you have the host ip addresses in the same network address range as the bridge IP address.
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test **openflow** servces is to use **mininet** emulator. Here is a tutorial on how to use it.

**http://mininet.org/walkthrough/**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The question is about how to create and OpenFlow network with a PC running OVS acting as a switch.

The host machines connected to the OVS PC have to access the internet only through OVS and not through the other interfaces.

I answered it below! 

Thanks